# upload new image/thumb to an existing carousel gallery/slider on wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, slider, carousel

My website is still not published so I hope you wont find it too hard to help me.

I'm new to wordpress and Ive just created my theme and activated it. On my index page I'm using a image carousel/slider to show some of my work.

My question is how can I upload new images without having to add new code to the page? I mean I can add new pages without having to code.

this is how Ive set it up:

```
<body>

<div class="featured-work-slides">
    <div id="home-carousel" class="home-carousel-thumbs img-wrap-thumbs">   


     <?php  $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_my_gallery ORDER BY id ASC"; $user_list = $wpdb->get_results($query); 

           foreach ($user_list as $user ) {
   ?>


                <figure class="thumb">
                  <a href="<?php echo $user->link; ?>" class="overlay">
                     <div class="inset-bevel">&nbsp;</div>
                         <img src="<?php echo WP_CONTENT_URL.'/uploads/my_gallery/'.$user->image_file_name; ?>" 
                    alt="Fantasy" width="300" height="300" />
                    <figcaption class="name">
                    <?php echo $user->image_title; ?>                   
                    </figcaption>
                </a>
                </figure>

                <?php } ?>
```

Hope my question and description is clear and thank you!

Comment: What are you using for the slider?  Is it a specific plugin?  A hard coded plugin or a drop in WordPress plugin?  I assume its a hard coded one based on your question, but wanted to verify.  If its hard coded, you're much better off finding one that is a WordPress plugin with an interface in the backend for you to upload new images.

Comment: @AndyWarren its hard coded =( thing is ive been searching for another slider but none are good looking, any tips?

Comment: Is it just images you're looking to put in the rotator?  Or would you like to rotate/slide content as well?  There are many good options, I just need a bit more information as to what you're after before I can make a recommendation.

Comment: @AndyWarren I'm just looking to rotate images/thumbs. Like a fixed image gallery that rotates, just want to use it to show my work and also let each image be a link to a page where more details about a specific job will be.

Comment: @AndyWarren the thing is that it is working great, only problem is that I can only add new images by adding a new code and its a shame that it has to go to waste...

Comment: My reply was too long to put in the comment box, so I added it below as an ansewr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotating Images plugin by iThemes is ideal if you just want to rotate/slide images and have them each contain their own URL when clicked.  It costs $25 for a for a 2 site license though, but there is a 35% discount code available: ELF2012 is the code.  You can find it here: http://ithemes.com/purchase/rotating-images/  I use this plugin very frequently as it is easy to use and has good features.  I would recommend this if you are willing to purchase it.

Nivo Slider is another great plugin; however I do not think it supports a unique URL beig applied to each image.  For the single site WordPress version it costs $19.

TheThe Image Slider is a free one, but I'm not sure of its linking capabilities either, but it has mostly good reviews.  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/thethe-image-slider/

Comment: Sorry if I misled you a bit there Andy, I dont want the images rotating. I want them placed next to each other, my images are 300x300 px and they move simultaneously in one direction with control panels on the left and right side.. Go to www.gomedia.us their top slider is nearly an exact version of mine.

Comment: Ya, sorry about that.  I guess I didn't fully catch what you were after.  I'll do some digging and try to reply again.

Comment: I found one that mostly does what you're looking for.  It has a couple downsides to it though.  The downside is that is doesn't look like it has a "full screen" option; however you can set the width and height.  It also does not have left/right controls.  It scrolls automatically and pauses on hover.  It doesn't have image upload capabilities, but you can use the wordpress uploader and then just drop in the URL in the plugin page.  Here's the download link:http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-horizontal-reel-scroll-slideshow/  On that page there is a live demo link with much more info.

Comment: thank you very much Andy I will have a look =) one more thing, what is the wordpress uploader its my first site so I know very little

Comment: In your WordPress admin area you have a "Media" admin menu item.  You can upload almost any file type with this.  It creates thumbnails of each image as well as maintains the original image.  Each image is given a unique URL as well.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it could.  The documentation says you can wrap items with links, and if I understand correctly, the "step" option lets you specify how many to show and scroll, and "visible" lets you specify how many to show at once.  It doesn't appear to be smooth scrolling though.  Its a jQuery UI plugin though, so you'd need to add the image code line each time a new one needs added, unless you built a custom post type to upload images to, and wrapped this rotator around it.

Comment: Then I'm better of using my own then :)